# Adding blog to Magento sitemap

Tags: magento, blogs, sitemap, magento-1.9

I installed Neotheme blog to my Magento 1.9, and I'm trying to figure out how to add it to my sitemap.xml. Default Google xml sitemap in Magento is not adding it, and there is no setting in the Neotheme blog to add it, or to make it's own sitemap.
I was trying to search Google for the solution, but I wasn't able to find  anything.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: If you want to add a link to the sitemap route in magento for neotheme use the following example modifying the url to match the blog path. Otherwise could you specify more precisely what your question is?
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
    </reference>

Comment: I'll try to clarify. My magento is creating sitemap.xml, but doesn't include blog in it, nor any blog posts. It creates sitemap that includes only default magento pages. I would like it to include new blog posts whenever it creates a sitemap.

Comment: Sounds like the module does not append the custom pages to the sitemap. I'd contact Neotheme and see if they offer a solution as it would have to be an observer than appends all the blog posts during sitemap generation/view controller.

Comment: Yeah, I contacted them and they told me the module doesn't support adding links to the sitemap. Thank you Vladimir!